# Kotlin Coroutines: runBlocking vs. coroutineScope

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am playing around with Kotlin Coroutines, and I ended up in a situation I do not understand. Let's say that I have two `suspend` functions:

```
suspend fun coroutine() {
    var num = 0
    coroutineScope {
        for (i in 1..1000) {
            launch {
                delay(10)
                num += 1
            }
        }
    }
    println("coroutine: $num")
}
```

and:

```
suspend fun runBlocked() = runBlocking {
    var num = 0
    for (i in 1..1000) {
        launch {
            delay(10)
            num += 1
        }
    }
    println("Run blocking: $num")
}
```

Then I call them from `main()` method:

```
suspend fun main() {
    coroutine()
    runBlocked()
}
```

The `coroutine()` method prints (as expected) a number that is almost never 1000 (usually between 970 and 999). And I understand why.

What I do not understand is why the `runBlocked()` function allways prints 0.

> coroutine: 998
> runBlocked: 0

I tried one more time, this time making a similar function to `runBlocked()`, with the difference that this time the method is returning a value instead of printing:

```
suspend fun runBlockedWithReturn(): Int = runBlocking {
    var num = 0
    for (i in 1..1000) {
        launch {
            delay(10)
            num += 1
        }
    }
    return@runBlocking num
}
```

And then I called it from the `main()` method:

```
suspend fun main() {
    val result = runBlockedWithReturn()
    println("Run blocking with return: $result")
}
```

...but the method returned 0.

Why is that? And how do I fix the `runBlocked()` method to print a number that is close to 1000 instead of 0? What am I missing?

Comment: In your examples, you are not calling `println` in the same location. In the first you are calling it immediately after `coroutineScope`, in the second you are calling it within `runBlocking`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`runBlocking` must never be called from a coroutine in the first place. Since we are violating this contract by putting it in a suspend function, any explanation we have for why it's behaving the way it is might be different on different platforms or in the future.

Aside from that, blocking code should never be called in a coroutine unless you are in a CoroutineContext that uses a dispatcher that can handle it, like `Dispatchers.IO`.

That said, the reason this is happening is that `coroutineScope` suspends until all of its children coroutines finish, and then you are logging after it returns. `runBlocking` behaves similarly, but you are logging from inside the block without waiting.

If you wanted to wait for all the coroutines launched before logging, you need to `join()` each of them. You can put them in a list and call `joinAll()` on it. For example:

```
(1..1000).map {
    launch {
        delay(10)
        num += 1
    }
}.joinAll()
```

But again, `runBlocking` should never be called in a coroutine. I'm only describing how you would do it if you were using `runBlocking` from outside a coroutine for its intended purpose, to bridge between non-coroutine and coroutine code.

Comment: `runBlocking` does indeed block until all of its children coroutines finish. The documentation states: 

"Runs a new coroutine and blocks the current thread interruptibly until its completion ... The default CoroutineDispatcher for this builder is an internal implementation of event loop that processes continuations in this blocked thread until the completion of this coroutine."

 The reason they are seeing different results is that in the `coroutineScope` example the `println` statement is just outside the block, while in the `runBlocking` example it is within the block.

Comment: @mithunc you’re absolutely right. I don’t remember writing this and have no idea why I would have put that. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Existing answers focus on what we should not do, but I think they miss the point, so the main reason why we see the difference.

Both `coroutineScope()` and `runBlocking()` guarantee that after exiting the code block all coroutines inside already finished running. But for some reason, I don't know if intentional or not, you wrote both cases differently. In `coroutine()` example you put `println()` below `coroutineScope()` block, so it is guaranteed to run after all children. On the other hand, in `runBlocked()` you put `println()` inside `runBlocking()`, so it runs concurrently to children. Just rewrite your `runBlocked()` in a similar way to `coroutine()`, so put `println()` below `runBlocking()` and you will see `1000`, as you expected.

Another difference between both examples is that by default `runBlocking()` runs using a single thread while `coroutineScope()` could use many of them. For this reason `coroutineScope()` produces a random value which is a result of unsafe sharing of a mutable state. `runBlocking()` is more predictable. It always produces `0` if `println()` is inside it, because `println()` runs before any children. Or it always produces `1000` if `println()` is below `runBlocking()`, because children are in fact running one at a time, they don't modify the value in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You should *never* call `runBlocking` from inside a `suspend fun`.

In any event, you don't wait for the launched coroutines to finish before you return a value from `runBlocking`, but your use of `coroutineScope` forces the launched coroutines in that function to complete before you get to the return.